# Adjusting kinect camera angle by v1.6 C#?

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

Anyone have any idea to do the adjusting of the angle of the kinect camera?

I have seen alot codes that is done in NUI

how about those without NUI ??

I have a slider , button and label inplaced .

Thanks

Comment: By Googling "kinect sdk adjust camera angle" I came across [this useful library](https://github.com/adevine1618/KinectSDK-Unity3D_Interface_Plugin).

Comment: KinectSensor.ElevationAngle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.elevationangle.aspx